# How to obtain samples from global maximum of a stochastic function?

Tags: probability, optimization, sampling

I would like to obtain samples of the value $\underset{x}{\arg\max} f(x)$, where the function $f$ is sampled from some distribution of functions $F$, i.e. $f\sim F$.

$x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

My intuition tells me that if I first sample a function $f$ and then solve for the $\arg\max$, I would obtain a sample from $\underset{x}{\arg\max} f(x)$. I'm skeptical of this, but I didn't find a way to prove or disprove this statement yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me a definitional (notational) matter of if that's what you mean, rather than a matter of proof. What you describe is how I would interpret it.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Didn't really understand your comment, can you rephrase it? :)

Comment: This is a matter of hoe you define what you want to do. it is not a matter oif proof.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Now I understand your sentence, thanks. My goal is to obtain samples from $\arg\max f(x)$, where $f$ is a stochastic function. Could you point out what is ambiguous or unclear about my question so I can improve it?

Comment: I interpreted it as you described in your first post. If there is an uncertainty, it is on your end.